# DirectoryIterator and array_pop and foreachloop of array

Tags: php

I have this snippet

```
$clusters = new DirectoryIterator("/agents/");
$cluster_array = array();

# Push each cluster into an array
foreach ($clusters as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo != "." && $fileinfo != ".." && $fileinfo != "conf") {
        array_push($cluster_array, $fileinfo->getFilename());
    }
}
```

this puts each folder it finds into my array, but my problem is that it keeps pushing the results at the begining of the array.

```
array([0]=>cluster_2, [1]=>cluster_1)
```

I want it to push the folders in order at the end of the array. I tried array_pop but i wasn't sure how to use it in this context.

After I have my array built, I wanted to scan thru each array and see how much free space was left with

```
foreach ($cluster_array as $cluster) {
    echo $cluster . " " . Server::server_free_space("/agents/" . $cluster, 2)."<br />";
}
```

that class method just uses `disk_free_space()` then converts the results into MB for me.

in-place of the echo statement I was going to do something like

```
if ((Server::server_total_space("/agents/" . $cluster, 2) / 3) > xMB) {

}
```

I wanted to create a folder into the first item in the array that has xMB available, if xMB isn't available then move onto the next array item and so on until it finds an array item that has the space required to make a new folder.

does this make sense?

EDIT:

I ended up doing this an build the array kinda manually

```
$clusters = new DirectoryIterator("/agents/");
$cluster_array = array();
$cluster_count = 0;

# Push each cluster into an array
foreach ($clusters as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo != "." && $fileinfo != ".." && $fileinfo != "conf") {
        array_push($cluster_array, "cluster_" . $cluster_count += 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: so what you stuck on what errors are you receiving, or is this just another code me question? just use: `sort($cluster_array)` to sort it.

Comment: that just returns 1 if i do a print_r on it. and no its not a code me question, its a help me build up my coding logic question ;-)

Comment: @s2xi: `sort($cluster_array);` alters the array by reference and returns a boolean value, not the sorted array. After the function call do `print_r($cluster_array);`, and you'll see a sorted array.

Comment: its ok, i did a makeshift version ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `array_push()` correctly, however `DirectoryIterator` and related iterators iterate through the items of the underlying filesystem, the way the operating system provides them. This is not necessarily sorted the way one might expect (naturally sorted, for instance). For a little more on this, also see this [faux bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45634).

Comment: ah, ya i had thought maybe it was something related to that. perhaps array_shift would do the trick

Comment: @s2xi: No, you'll need to sort them with some sorting function afterwards, for instance like [Lawrence Cherone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211334/directoryiterator-and-array-pop-and-foreachloop-of-array/7211375#comment-8665058) suggested